# How do I enable IIS Express to serve external requests over Port 80

Tags: iis-express, webapi, visual-studio-2022

I am developing a WebAPI in Visual Studio 2022.  I wish to share testing of the code under development with a colleague in our corporate network over port 80.  I have previously accomplished this under VS 2017 on a different machine using the following technique:

1/  Use netsh to reserve the relevant URL

2/  Add the binding information to the IIS Express Config:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:machinename" />
```

3/  Modified the firewall to allow the requests through:

```
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 80 IISExpressWeb enable ALL
```

Unfortunately, this tried and trusted procedure doesn't appear to have worked (employed the same technique from VS2010 onwards).  What is happening here? I think this should work.

Comment: Could you use IIS instead, thus making it simple?

Comment: Unfortunately no, full IIS implementations are in the hands of our corporate IT, and the code is not in a state where I can deploy it to our dev web-server, which entails a raft of paperwork to get the API authorised and deployed.

Comment: What error does the remote machine give?