# How do I enable IIS Express to serve external requests

Tags: visual-studio-2022, iis-express

This is a re-post of [an earlier issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70453271/how-do-i-enable-iis-express-to-serve-external-requests-over-port-80?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C231.7799). After a long hiatus with respect to this topic I am back to it again.

I need to make my local dev IIS Express instance available to colleagues for testing purposes.  After much reading and many blind alleys, I managed to get a little bit further than I did when this was originally posted, in that I have managed to get VS 2022 to recognise the entries from the applicationHost.config that are needed, unfortunately when I debug the website, IIS Express (or rather MS Edge) responds with:

> Hmmm... Cant reach this page
> machinename.euro.org.local refused to connect

Note the URL is obfuscated for security reasons.

The applicationHost.config file contains the following entries:

```
 ...
        <site name="appName" id="1">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\appPath\appName" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:machinename.euro.org.local" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44379:machinename.euro.org.local" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

VS confirms that the virtual directory has been successfully created.

I have made the necessary additions to `HTTP.SYS`:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://machinename.euro.org.local:8080/ user=everyone
```

and to my firewall settings:

```
netsh firewall add portopening TCP 8080 IISExpressWeb enable ALL
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Normally we discourage duplicate posts - Stack Overflow is intended to be a collection of useful Q&A, not a forum, so duplication is something we strive to avoid. However, in this case, your other question did not attract any answers, possibly because someone asked for clarification, and there was no answer; in this case you could probably just delete the other question, as it is not useful to keep.

Comment: I note though that your other question is posted from another user account - have you lost the credentials for the other one? I believe mods can merge accounts where that is useful.

Comment: Nothing changes from that thread. In a corporate network, full IIS is still best shot. The new Dev Tunnels in VS 2022 might work for other developers, but less likely you, https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/11/18/dev-tunnels.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To access IIS Express from the local network, you need to change the "launchSettings.json" parameters (the "PublishProfiles" folder in the project).
In the "IIS Express" section you need to change the key (example):
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15286",
to
"applicationUrl": "http://192.168.1.10:15286",

Where 192.168.1.10 - is the address of the PC on the local network.
This method will work if:

- When starting the project, IIS Express is used;
- An http connection is used;
- Visial Studio is running with administrator rights.

You can also do port forwarding and your project will become accessible from the Internet.